# Do I need transit visa or get pre-arrival registeration to go to Japan via Hong Kong?

Tags: india, japan, hong-kong, cathay-pacific

I hold an Indian passport and am planning to visit Japan via Hong Kong ( Cathay Pacific ). There is a layover of about 2 hours. Do I need to get preregistration done ? I am not planning to leave the airport and will just be changing flights.